# Why does write-host output to transcript but write-information does not?

Tags: powershell, logging, write-host

This one is confusing me and wondered if anyone could shed some light on this, maybe also answer 2 parts with this one example?

I have a Powershell script I run like a batch file and I have it output values it has captured from a separate file out to a log. This particular part is not outputting in the transcript where I get the DB version of a database. I have tried different placements of the `"`, using `$DBVersion` on it's own and this is a simple way to show what I have trouble with. e.g.:

```
## Read the DBs Extended properties
Function Get-DB_Version {
Param (
    $SQLInstance,
    $DBName
)
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $DBName -Query "SELECT value FROM fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default) WHERE name = 'version'"
}
**Other Variables used are also pre-set above here **


## Get DB version
$DBVersion = Get-DB_Version -SQLInstance $SQLInstance -DBName $DBName



Start-Transcript -Path "$LogOutput\$LogName" -IncludeInvocationHeader -Append 

Write-Information "
**** DEBUG INFO ****
Write-Host "Debug:"$DBVersion.value
Write-Information "Debug:"$DBVersion.value
Read-Host -Prompt "PAUSE" # This is so I can visually see the console seeing only the write-host is there as expected.

Stop-Transcript
```

In my log file I get the output:

> Debug: 2.16.51443.5147
>
> INFO: Debug:

This shows me that the variable contains a value as the write-host outputs it, however when use `Write-Information` it does not show anything in the log, All other variables I use do show, why would `$DBVersion.value` or `$DBVersion` not show anything please?

Also the second part is, why do I have to use:

```
$DBVersion.value
```

Outside of the `write-host ""` quotes?

Many thank in Advance

Comment: To put it simply, it's read as 2 separate commands and not just one.  So, it first runs `Write-Host "...."`, then it runs `$DBVersion.Value`. if you want it in the same line, you need to place the variable **inside** the quotes, then using the sub-expression operator `$()` to expand the value inside the quotes: `Write-Host "Debug: $($DBVersion.value)"`. Same goes for your `Write-Information`.

Comment: In addition to Abraham's helpful comment, you don't need either of those cmdlet but in any case, `Write-Information` doesn't produce any output by itself, you would need to set `$InformationPreference = 'Continue'` at the top of your script or use the `-InformationAction Continue` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As @abraham said in the comments. All I had to do, to have the variable inside of the quotes (my question 2) was use the sub-expression operator `$()` to expand the value inside the quotes: `Write-Host "Debug: $($DBVersion.value)"`. The same goes for your `Write-Information`.

Doing this alone also resolved my original question of why `Write-Information` didn't output anything into the transaction logs and I did NOT need to change the $InformationPreference.